# How to parse malformed HTML in python

Tags: python, html, lxml

I need to browse the DOM tree of a parsed HTML document.

I'm using uTidyLib before parsing the string with lxml

a = tidy.parseString(html_code, options)
dom = etree.fromstring(str(a))

sometimes I get an error, it seems that tidylib is not able to repair malformed html.

how can I parse every HTML file without getting an error (parsing only some parts of files that can not be repaired)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) does a good job with invalid/broken HTML

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<htm@)($*><body><table <tr><td>hi</tr></td></body><html")
>>> print soup.prettify()
<htm>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     hi
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</htm>
```

Answer (score 13):

Since you are already using lxml, have you tried [lxml's](http://lxml.de/) [ElementSoup](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) module?

If ElementSoup can't repair the HTML then you'll probably need to apply your own filters first that are based on your own observations of how the data is broken.

Comment: Links were broken; edited them.  Hopefully the new locations contain the same content that you were originally pointing to.

Comment: If you don't have beautiful soup installed, you may need it for Element Soup. Just do `pip install beautifulsoup`