# Extracting Items from HTML using Python

Tags: python, html

I need to extract some information from not very complicated HTML pages in web. I don't need to *crawl* or anything, just some XPath selectors or similar.

which library is the fastest in mean of setting up and coding (i.e. getting quick results!)? Scrapy, BeautifulSoap, ..., or basic HTMLParser?

Comment: Is the HTML guaranteed to be valid XHTML?

Comment: nope. it might even contains errors.

Comment: What part of the search button wasn't working on Stack Overflow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse malformed HTML in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904644/how-to-parse-malformed-html-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some experience with `BeautifulSoup` and was able to get results out in a matter of minutes. The following tutorial page was very helpful, with lots of examples:

[Leonard Richardson's BeautifulSoup Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html)

Comment: Your answer seems perfect, but I have a query does `BeautifulSoup` supports xpath expressions.I have never used `BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I haven't used XPath with `BeautifulSoup`, but looking around online, it seems that people have been able to tease out what they need. Sorry I can't help too much, there.

Answer (score 3):

[`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is great. Try it. It can fix up erroneous HTML sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) is great. Try it.

Example:

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.parse('url to parse')
content_parsed  = doc.xpath('xpath expre here')
```

And if you just want to sanitize the html look at the lxml.html.clean [module](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html). Also note that the [ElementSoup](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) enables lxml.html to use the BeautifulSoup parser should it be necessary