# Python regex findall to capture repeated groups

Tags: python, regex, scrapy, findall

## Context

I am using python [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) to parse some HTMLs because they are too broken to use processors better suited for those tasks (e.g. scrapy selectors). An excerpt of the HTML I want to parse looks like this:

```
<LI><B>First list title</B> Additional info
  <UL>
  <LI><I>List element 1</I> additional info
  </UL>

<LI><B>Second list title</B> Additional info
  <UL>
  <LI><I>List element 1</I> additional info1
  <LI><I>List element 2</I> additional info2
  <LI><I>List element 3</I> additional info3
  <LI><I>List element 4</I> additional info4
  </UL>

<!-- many more elements like the ones above -->
```

I need to capture the List title (and additional information), and for each title all nested elements it has with their additional information as well.

## Approaches

```
import regex as re
```

### re.findall

```
reg = re.compile("<li><b>(.*)\n\s*<ul>\n(\s*<li>.+\n)+\s*</ul>", re.IGNORECASE)
g_info = re.findall(reg, response.body)
```

If we look info g_info in the above example we will see that for those with one list element is fine:

```
g_info[0] <- ('First list title</B> Additional info', "  <LI><I>List element 1</I> additional info\n")
```

But when there are multiple sublist elements, only the last one is obtained.

```
g_info[1] <- ('Second list title</B> Additional info', "  <LI><I>List element 4</I> additional info4\n")
```

I would like it to be something like:

```
g_info[1] <- ('Second list title</B> Additional info', "  <LI><I>List element 1</I> additional info1\n", "  <LI><I>List element 2</I> additional info2\n", ...)
```

### re.search and .captures

Using the same regular expression I can use the .captures function to get all the elements captured. I will tune it slightly so it works with this example:

```
reg = re.compile("<li><b>(.*)\n\s*<ul>\n(\s*<li>.+\n){2,}\s*</ul>", re.IGNORECASE)
g_info = re.search(reg, response.body)
```

But this way (I would further parse each element with another simpler regexp to obtain what I want) I only get the first match and not all of them.

```
g_info.captures() <-- '<LI><B>Second list title</B> Additional info\n  <UL>\n  <LI><I>List element 1</I> additional info1\n  <LI><I>List element 2</I> additional info2\n ...'
```

If I could get all of them in this format it would suffice for me.

### re.findall and additional looping and filtering

I could use a simpler regexp to get all of them. Then I could further detect which is a subelement and which not, because list titles always start with a bold  tag and the others don't.

```
reg = re.compile("(\s*<li>.+\n)", re.IGNORECASE)
g_info = re.findall(reg, response.body)
```

What I get is something like this:

```
g_info[0] <- '\n\n<LI><B>First list title</B> Additional info\n'
g_info[1] <- '\n  <LI><I>List element1</I> additional info\n'
g_info[2] <- '\n\n<LI><B>Second list title</B> Additional info\n'
g_info[3] <- '\n  <LI><I>List element</I> additional info1\n'
g_info[4] <- '  <LI><I>List element2</I> additional info2\n'
g_info[5] <- '  <LI><I>List element3</I> additional info3\n'
```

## Solutions?

The only workable approach I found was the last one, which imho is not elegant. Could you help me find a better solution? Thanks

Comment: How about using something like `re.compile("<li>([^\r\n]+)", re.IGNORECASE)` with `findall`? It gives you [that](http://regex101.com/r/cD5iC6) (without newlines or the `<LI>` tag). But that's assuming I understood what you were really after. I'd otherwise recommend trying BeautifulSoup.

Comment: What should your end result be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(?<=<li><b>).*?(?=</ul>)", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
print re.findall(pattern, data)
```

**Output**

```
['First list title</B> Additional info\n  <UL>\n  <LI><I>List element 1</I> additional info\n  ',
 'Second list title</B> Additional info\n  <UL>\n  <LI><I>List element 1</I> additional info1\n  <LI><I>List element 2</I> additional info2\n  <LI><I>List element 3</I> additional info3\n  <LI><I>List element 4</I> additional info4\n  ']
```

Answer (score 2):

regex to parse html is not a good idea and should be avoided as much as possible [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

before taking that path, I'd re-evaluate "they are too broken" and try to do my best to parse / debug them, see [How to parse malformed HTML in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904644/how-to-parse-malformed-html-in-python)