# BeautifulSoup find unwrapped text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i have html document that may contain unwrapped text, all this text i need wrap in `<p>`.
Example:

```
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
other text
<b>Some text</b>
```

I need that this html transform like this:

```
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p>other text</p>
<p><b>Some text</b></p>
```

But i does find bs method that find unwrapped dom nodes. 
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what BeautifulSoup does. It is a library for extracting information from HTML, not for writing HTML. You should use the underlying XML library instead.

Comment: @Atsch, do you know some custom libraries that can help me?

Comment: it's not very clear to me what you want to do

Comment: i has html files on input, i dont create html, i need to manipulate him

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293482/how-do-i-fix-wrongly-nested-unclosed-html-tags) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904644/how-to-parse-malformed-html-in-python), maybe they'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
​
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
other text
<b>Some text</b>""")
​
```

Firstly use `soup.find` to get the parent node of all the interesting nodes, and then for all the interesting nodes, if it is not a p node, wrap it with a tag p, A string node is treated differently because they contain new line characters and needs to be stripped off:

```
for child in soup.find('body').children:
    if isinstance(child, NavigableString):
        p = soup.new_tag('p')
        p.append(child.strip())
        child.replace_with(p)
    elif child.name != 'p': 
        child.wrap(soup.new_tag('p'))

soup
<html>
    <body>
        <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        <p>other text</p>
        <p><b>Some text</b></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you don't care about new line characters, it could simply be like:

```
for child in soup.find('body').children:
    if child.name != 'p': 
        child.wrap(soup.new_tag('p'))
```

Comment: Great answer, question is using isinstance better?

Comment: thanx great solution, if i have "<b>lorem</b>, some text", can i wrap such string in one paragraph?

Comment: @ElvirMuslic Good point. I agree it's better to use `isinstance`.

Comment: @nueq I would say it's possible but may not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at it as a string in which case you can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and find the text your'e looking for.

Once  you know what the area looks like you can search for it in the string and add your

Here is a regex example:

```
>>> s = """<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    other text
    <b>Some text</b>"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'</\w>\s*[\w\s]+\s*<\w>',s)
>>> m
['</p>\nother text\n<b>']
```

\w matches any character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9)

\s matches any whitespace

'*' means 0 or more repititions

[\w ] means either a letter or a whitespace character

'+' means 1 or more repetitions

for more details on regex and how to use it look at [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)